# Android How to identify carrier on CDMA network?

Tags: android

Android provides the following method to determine the network operator:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName()

However even the documentation specifically says:

> Returns the alphabetic name of current registered operator.
>   Availability: Only when user is registered to a network. **Result may be unreliable on CDMA networks** (use getPhoneType() to determine if on a CDMA network).

The problem is that we need a **reliable** way to detect the carrier so we can identify the traffic source.  Has anyone had a similar problem and if so, what is the best solution?

Comment: Well, use the method provided in the link, if it returns null or invalid results use getPhoneType().

Comment: getPhoneType will tell us that we _are_ on a CDMA network, but we need to identify **which** CDMA network are we on (ie which carrier)

Answer (score 2):

My phone is on Verizon Wireless. On a daily basis, I drive through areas where my phone is roaming and/or has poor reception. Using scripting layer for android, I will log the results of calling getOperatorName() once every ten minutes over the next week.

There is [another method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/cdma/CdmaCellLocation.html#getNetworkId%28%29) that might work in the android.telephony.cdma api. The documentation there is missing the reliability disclaimer. You would only get a Network ID instead of a name. Unfortunately, this requires API level 5 instead of 1 if that matters to you.

Logging the results of the getOperatorName() method yielded nothing special. When I had no service it consistently returned null and when I had service it consistently returned "Verizon Wireless." I'm sure that's not very helpful.

Edit: Addition and correction.
Added - Explanation of link
Corrected - API level 5 not 17

Edit 2: Test results

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. When linking, try to add the essential parts to your answer here.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean add a comment with the essential parts in it, or should I have included more information to explain the link I put in my answer?

Comment: No problem. I usually like to see the essential parts of the information contained on a refrerred link right in the answer. Sometimes it is possible to give the essential information in a way the asker can implement a solution without reading the whole reference. If you believe this is not the case, don't worry, and welcome again =)

Comment: Up voted. Thanks for test results. It seems that the method is not so unreliable after all.

Comment: Actually it is unreliable. I also got results like home, school, cricket etc form users. But it gives correct operator more often then operator alias like these.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking for a solution for this problem as well. According to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/ASVpv7RbLL8) one could use `CdmaCellLocation.getNetworkId` and `CdmaCellLocation.getSystemId`. Since there are no CDMA networks in Germany, I am unable to check if this works...

Answer (score -1):

You think maybe this was one precurser to Google pulling cdma support?  Play within the frameworks or find you another playground is what I hear Google saying.  Well that and the fact that carrier apps burned into roms have at times left gaping holes in security.
As to a possible answer to your question... from where are you able to pull info?  APN settings might tell you or an assert to a known carrier line in build.prop could pull the info I might need for example. (I do the hobby roms).  Then again if you physically inspect a phone, the carrier is usually branded ;)  From what vantage are you pulling the info?

Rob